# Get command return in systemd service file as in Shell script

Tags: systemd, coreos

I have a CoreOS cluster in which i have a SystemD service that just run a Docker container. However, for flexibility purpose, i want the Docker Registry the container gets pulled from to be discovered when the service start, what i do easily using Etcd (the node discovery system from the CoreOS project).

So, i tried it in a normal terminal, what just gives me a command like this `/usr/bin/etcdctl get /services/registry`to get the current IP address of the registry. And it works! But from a SystemD service, the command is returned as typed and not executed as someone should do in a Shell script with backticks. I tried backticks, `$()` and `${}`syntaxes but the command is still returned as is.

If anybody has a suggestion, i'm taking it :) Thanks!

Comment: Two suggestions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47695/how-to-write-startup-script-for-systemd and https://github.com/jordansissel/pleaserun

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make your ExecStart use `/bin/sh -c "echo $(etcdctl ls /)"` it will perform in the way that you desire.

Here's a full unit file taking advantage of this:
https://github.com/coreos/unit-examples/blob/master/simple-fleet/apache-discovery.2.service#L6

Comment: Thanks, @Deer Hunter & @Rob! It works :) It seems Systemd does not support string extrapolation ...